# Nested JSON objects and arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to create JSON object with a structure which looks like

```
  {
     "events": [
        {
           "eventId": <string>,
           "location": <string>,
           "dates": [<string>, <string>],
           "price": <number>,
           "options": [
              {
                 "name": <string>, 
                 "code": <number>, 
                 "surcharge": <number>
              }, {}, {}...
           ],
        }, {}, {}...
     ]
  }
```

my test PHP code looks like

```
    $event_data[] = array(
        "eventId" => 'A001',
        "location" => 'Pool',
        "dates" => array('2017-10-15T11:45:00Z','2017-10-15T18:00:00Z'),
        "price" => 125,
         "options" => array(
             { 
             "name" => "soda", 
             "code" => 1, 
             "surcharge" => 0
             },  
             { 
              "name" => "beer", 
              "code" => 2, 
              "surcharge" => 25
            }
            )
     );
$data = json_encode(array('evets' => $event_data));
```

somehow I'm not able to create JSON object field `options` as an array of other JSON to get it as

```
           "options": [
              {
                 "name": <string>, 
                 "code": <number>, 
                 "surcharge": <number>
              },
              {
                 "name": <string>, 
                 "code": <number>, 
                 "surcharge": <number>
              },
              {
                 "name": <string>, 
                 "code": <number>, 
                 "surcharge": <number>
              }
           ],
```

I know I have done something wrong in that place but have no clue what.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Javascript objects are arrays or objects in php. The `{...}` notation is not used in php for either. You should use `array(...)` or `[...]` (both for arrays).

Comment: replace `{}` with `array()`

Comment: i think you want like this:- `"options" => array(
             array( 
             "name" => "soda", 
             "code" => 1, 
             "surcharge" => 0
             ),  
             array( 
              "name" => "beer", 
              "code" => 2, 
              "surcharge" => 25
            )
  )`

Comment: @AlivetoDie yeah - that did the job. Thanks!

Comment: If you enable error reporting in your development environment, and write your code in an editor that's aware of PHP syntax, basic syntax errors like this will be more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your option array like below:-

```
"options" => array(
             array( 
             "name" => "soda", 
             "code" => 1, 
             "surcharge" => 0
             ),  
             array( 
              "name" => "beer", 
              "code" => 2, 
              "surcharge" => 25
            )
        )
```

Output:- https://eval.in/858403